# Access an injected Stateful Session Bean over a looked up Stateful Session Bean

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, jboss-eap-7, stateful

I was wondering if EJB specifications allow to access a stateful session bean over a looked up stateful session bean.

The reason why I'm asking is, that Jboss EAP 7.0 has no problems with it, but Websphere throws a NullPointerException when I try to access the bean.

For example:

```
@Stateful
public class SampleServiceRoot implements SampleServiceRootRemote {

    @EJB
    protected SampleServiceChildLocal servicechild;

    @Override
    public SampleServiceChildLocal getServiceChild(){
        return servicechild;
    }
}

@Stateful
public class SampleServiceChild implements SampleServiceChildLocal,SampleServiceChildRemote{

    @Override       
    public void anyMethod(){
      //DO Anything
    }
}
```

When I do a remote lookup to the SampleServiceRootRemote and call "getServiceChild()" and try to call "anyMethod()" on it, it works on JBoss EAP 7.0 but on Websphere I get a NullPointerException.

So I was wondering if this is a Bug in Websphere or is it forbidden by EJB Specification and I was just lucky with JBoss EAP 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

The EJB specification does require this scenario to work, depending on some configuration options; there are configuration options that may disable it.

The fact that you are seeing a NullPointerException indicates that WebSphere is not aware of the `@EJB` annotation on the field in the `SampleServiceRoot` class. Per the EJB specification, an instance of `SampleServiceRoot` cannot be created if the `@EJB` annotation cannot be resolved.  Since an instance of `SampleServiceRoot` has been created, then one of the following has likely occurred:

1 - The application performed a `new SampleServiceRoot` rather than looking it up in JNDI. This doesn't sound like your problem, but good to double check.

2 - The application contains an `ejb-jar.xml` with the setting `metadata-complete="true"`.  When this is set, WebSphere will not look for annotations, and so will not see or process the `@EJB` annotation.  Either change the setting to "false" or add the `<ejb-ref>` or `<ejb-local-ref>` to the `ejb-jar.xml` file.

3 - The application does not have `metadata-complete="true"`, however when the application is deployed to WebSphere the option to set metadata-complete was selected.
This option will change the metadata-complete setting to "true". Stop using this option, or add the `<ejb-ref>` or `<ejb-local-ref>` to the `ejb-jar.xml` file.

4 - The EJB is contained in a WAR module at level 2.4 or older. In WebSphere, annotations for older modules are not processed.

5 - The application includes a copy of the `javax.ejb.EJB` class. WebSphere provides the `javax.ejb.EJB` class, and it is loaded by the WebSphere runtime classloader.  If the application also contains the `javax.ejb.EJB` class on the application classpath, then another instance will be loaded by the application classloader, and it will not match the instance used by the EJB Container.  There should be a warning in the logs if this has occurred.

So yes, your scenario is required to be supported; however the specification does allow configurations that disable it. You just need to identify which configuration / packaging option has caused WebSphere to not see the `@EJB` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer,

we tried to move the declarations of the Local-Interface to the Remote Interface of the SampleServiceChild. Also we did not use @EJB annotation. We managed it with doing a lookup of the SampleServiceChild over the InitialContext.
Now it works